# C# console application not writing logs in application insight when run as docker image

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-application-insights

I have written a c# console application and using Ilogger I am writing log traces in Application insight. I am writing Information,debug,critical and error logs . It woks fine when I am running it locally but when I am creating a docker image and running the image the logs are not written in Application insight

```
        ILogger<Program> logger = (ILogger<Program>)LoggingWorker.GetLogger();
        logger.LogWarning("Log Warming");
        logger.LogInformation("Log info");
        logger.LogDebug("Test Debug");
        logger.LogError("Test Error");
        logger.LogCritical("Test Critical");
        Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
```

Code for LoggingWorker Class

```
public static class LoggingWorker
{

    private static IServiceProvider GetServiceProvider()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();           
        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace));
        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        return serviceProvider;
    }
    public static ILogger GetLogger()
    {
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = GetServiceProvider();
        ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        return logger;
    }

}
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myproj.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "myproj.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "myproj.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myproj.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproj.dll"]
```

Please suggest what I might be doing wrong

Comment: check for connectionstring to connect application insights if it is accessible from docker.

Comment: Yes it works because when I add telemetry code to insert custom event in App Insight it work fine. the issue is only with Log traces.

Comment: compare your log level in appsettings.json and appsetting,development.json. in case of docker it runs in production mode so it will take log levels from appsettings.json. but when you run locally it takes from appsetting,development.json.